# application-multipart ajax post form data - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, multipartform-data

I need to POST inputted data from a form in a multipart/form-data format to a url.

Currently I have been using ajax calls, but Not sure what I am missing / how do I get the ajax call to get the multipart/form-data from the form.

this is part of my html :

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate autocomplete="off" name="stepOne" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>First Name </label>
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

This is my JS :

```
 $.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType:attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert("success: " + data);
    },
    error:function(error){
        alert("error: " + error);
    }
});
```

Thank You!

Comment: Are you using multipart because you're uploading a file with the formdata? What is the actual issue you're having?

Comment: I need to send the form data in a 'multipart form data' for the url to accept it. I am not 100% sure what  multipart form data is to be honest.